# Very simple entry and exit strategy

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

I'm new to pine and strategy scripting. I wanna use entry's with a stoploss and a take profit. But not all my signals are triggered. What needs to be done:

1. The script should only take a position if no positions are taken already.
2. Since I'm trading on the Nasdaq all prices are in dollar's. In this example I need a profit of 0.21 dollar. I wanna use as stoploss the low of the entry candle that is triggered by the buy_signal condition.

I'm using this Pine code:

`buy_signal = trueConditionOne and trueConditionTwo and trueConditionThree strategy.entry('Buy',  strategy.long,  when = buy_signal) strategy.exit("Exit Long", from_entry="Buy", profit=0.21, loss=low -1)`

In the screenshot is each green arrow below a candle a signal that is triggered with the same conditions that buy_signal has. In the screenshot there are no 3 entry's/exit's. What I need for this in my code?

Thanks in advance,

Mark

I tried different stoploss and coding sites to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You should try this (in pinescript v5) :

```
buy_signal = trueConditionOne and trueConditionTwo and trueConditionThree 
if strategy.opentrades == 0
    if buy_signal
        strategy.entry("entry", strategy.long)
        strategy.exit("SL", from_entry="entry", limit=(close+0.21), stop=low)
```

Comment: So in in pine scrip, you define the SL and the TP in the same API? SL is defined as the parameter stop and TP is the parameter limit